# Nuxt.js calling axios to get a local file fails with 404. However calling external URL then changing to local file works

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Stripping down to the minimal vue file, following is what I have.

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <pre>{{html_data}}</pre>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
const axios = require('axios');

let url="/test.txt";

export default {
    asyncData: async function() {
        let result = await axios.get(url);
        return { html_data: result.data };
    },
}
</script>
```

I can see that the nuxt's local file looks at static folder, so I placed my test.txt file in static folder. And I am able to access `http://localhost:3000/test.txt` without 404 not found.

Opening `http://localhost:3000/axios` (my vue file's name is axios.vue), the screen shows `NuxtServerError Request failed with status code 404`. However, if I change the url to external (such as `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`) it works perfectly fine.

What is more odd is that once I open external site, and change the url and wait for the hot reload, the local file using `let url="/test.txt";` displays as expected.

What exactly am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with Nuxt but why do you expect `/axios` to resolve to anything?

Comment: That is how nuxt works with the automated routing. By the way, what was your edit purpose?

Comment: Ah ok, so your `axios.vue` is one of your _pages_. Got it. My edit just added HTML syntax colouring to your code block. You can see the diff here ~ https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61051767/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like making Axios requests to files in the static directory doesn't work when called from inside `asyncData()`. You have to specify the whole URL (with the base, so `http://localhost:3000/test.txt` in your case) or make the request in the `mounted()` hook.

Someone had a similar experience in this [issue](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1850#issuecomment-336544027).